# Amazon Linux2 - java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel How to set JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, amazon-linux-2

## How to set JAVA_HOME in Amazon Linux2?

While I am installing spark 2.4.7 using `ansible playbook`,
I want to set JAVA_HOME.

I installed java-1.8.0 using yum.

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64
```

And I found directory like below.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.272.b10-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/
```

but directory with all minor + patch version seems to be very vulnerable for future change.
Is there more stable directory name for JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 1):

I made a ugly workaround.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(realpath $(dirname $(realpath `which java`))/../..)
```

any comment or pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: Hm I had the same problem, but I resolved it by creating a symlink and then referencing the symlink, the symlink will be referencing any of the java versions with that long name, and you just will need to update the symlink when needed. I don't know if that can fit your requirements.